# Signalr - It's possible to wait reponse from client?

Tags: c#, signalr

I am a beginner in using Signalr and am checking out some examples.

Is it possible to send a message to the client from the server and wait for a return from it? Or is it possible to guarantee that after the answer the same session will be used?

My question is because in a given process, within a transaction, I need to ask the user if he wants to continue with the changes. I have not been able to ask this question before because validations should be done in the same session where changes have been made (but not yet confirmed).

Comment: There is no such thing like *response* in signalR, you can make a call from client to server after you receive a notification. Edit your post with the code you have tried and I can lend you some help.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Actually I do not have code developed yet. I am studying and looking for examples on the internet for this purpose. If you know of any material or example with this solution please inform me.

Comment: Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75100129/4393935) in this thread as this is now possible using .NET 7.

Answer (score 13):

Reiterating the comment from Jaime Yule, WebSockets are bidirectional communication and do not follow the Request/Response architecture for messaging. Given the very fluid nature of communication around WebSockets, these bullet points are good to keep in mind for your current (& future) scenarios:

- SignalR is great if you're going to use it for fire & forget (Display a pop-up to a user and that's it)
- It's not designed around request-response like you're asking, and trying to use it as such is an anti-pattern
- Messages may be sent from either end of the connection at any time,
  and there is no native support for one message to indicate it is
  related to another
- This makes the protocol poorly suited for transactional requirements

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75100129/4393935) in this thread as this is now possible using .NET 7.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible, but i would not recommend (relying on) it.
And it's not a pretty solution (using a static event and being pretty complex for such a simple thing).

Story goes like this:

Make sure client and server know the `connectionId` - They probably know that already, but i could not figure out a way to access it.

Await `NotificationService.ConfirmAsync`
... which will call `confirm` on the client
... which will await the user supplied answer
... and send it back to the server using `Callback` from The hub.
... which will notify the Callback from the `NotificationService` over a static event
... which will hand off the `message` back to `ConfirmAsync` (using a `AutoResetEvent`)
... which is hopefully still waiting :)

Client and server both have a 10 second timeout set.

The hub:

```
    // Setup as /notification-hub
    public class NotificationHub : Hub {
        public string ConnectionId() => Context.ConnectionId;
        public static event Action<string, string> Response;
        public void Callback(string connectionId, string message) {
            Response?.Invoke(connectionId, message);
        }
    }
```

Service:

```
    // Wire it up using DI
    public class NotificationService {
        private readonly IHubContext<NotificationHub> _notificationHubContext;
        public NotificationService(IHubContext<NotificationHub> notificationHubContext) {
            _notificationHubContext = notificationHubContext;
        }

        public async Task<string> ConfirmAsync(string connectionId, string text, IEnumerable<string> choices) {
            await _notificationHubContext.Clients.Client(connectionId)
                                         .SendAsync("confirm", text, choices);
            var are = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            string response = null;
            void Callback(string connId, string message) {
                if (connectionId == connId) {
                    response = message;
                    are.Set();
                }
            }
            NotificationHub.Response += Callback;
            are.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            NotificationHub.Response -= Callback;
            return response;
        }
    }
```

Client side js:

```
    var conn = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/notification-hub").build();
    var connId;

    // using Noty v3 (https://ned.im/noty/)
    function confirm(text, choices) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var n = new Noty({
                text: text,
                timeout: 10000,
                buttons: choices.map(function (b) {
                    return Noty.button(b, 'btn', function () {
                        resolve(b);
                        n.close();
                    });
                })
            });
            n.show();
        });
    }

    conn.on('confirm', function(text, choices) {
        confirm(text, choices).then(function(choice) {
            conn.invoke("Callback", connId, choice);
        });
    });

    conn.start().then(function() {
        conn.invoke("ConnectionId").then(function (connectionId) {
            connId = connectionId;
            // Picked up by a form and posted to the server
            document.querySelector(".connection-id-input").value = connectionId;
        });
    });
```

For me this is way to complex to put it into the project i am working on.
It really looks like something that will come back and bite you later...

Answer (score 3):

This is now possible with .NET 7 using [Client Results](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-7.0#client-results).

Today, I've highlighted [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/28078) in dotnet's Github page and got a good response from one of the developers of SignalR.

This requires the server to use [ISingleClientProxy.InvokeAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.isingleclientproxy?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to be able to make request to the client and wait for response.

Quote from the documentation

> In addition to making calls to clients, the server can request a
> result from a client. This requires the server to use
> ISingleClientProxy.InvokeAsync and the client to return a result from
> its .On handler.

From the client (js/ts)

```js
hubConnection.on("GetMessage", async () => {
  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(new { data: "message" });
    }, 100);
  });
  return promise;
});
```

From the server (C#)

```cs
//By calling Client(...) on an instance of IHubContext<T>
async Task<object> SomeMethod(IHubContext<MyHub> context)
{
    string result = await context.Clients.Client(connectionID).InvokeAsync<string>(
        "GetMessage");
    return result;
}

//---------------------------//

//Or by calling Client(...) or Caller on the Clients property in a Hub method
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public async Task<string> WaitForMessage(string connectionId)
    {
        var message = await Clients.Client(connectionId).InvokeAsync<string>(
            "GetMessage");
        return message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to send a message to the client from the server and wait for a return from it? Or is it possible to guarantee that after the answer the same session will be used?

None of this is possible. Currently there's no way to wait for the client's response or even to get to know if the client received the message. There's some discussion implementing this on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/1300#issuecomment-358385411). Also here's the feature [request](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5280).

Until then, the workaround is to send a "notification" from the server with a fire and forget attitude and let the client get the required data via a HTTP request to the server.

Answer (score -2):

Using the following form with Invoke waits for and returns the response directly (just like a "real" synchronous method call)

```
        var persons = hubProxy.Invoke<IEnumerable<Person>>("GetPersonsSynchronous", SearchCriteria, noteFields).Result;

        foreach (Person person in persons)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{person.LastName}, {person.FirstName}");
        }
```