# ASP NET Core SignalR respond back to client from another Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

So I am developing a website in ASP NET Core. and that website uses SignalR

Now I have another Service which does some stuff. I want it to respond back to the client after sometime that the task is completed.

Now I am a little confused on how to do this.

My thought is to connect the Service with the SingalR hub and then send the respond back to client.

And the client can also communicate with it via the Hub.

Is there a better way?

I also did search for RabbitMQ but that seemed really high level for my use case or is it the right solution?

But still the issue remains to send the respond back to client later.

Thanks

Comment: What you looking for is event-driven architecture. You might achieve your goal via SignalR but I think sub-pub kinda solution is more convinient

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Signalr - It's possible to wait reponse from client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48288284/signalr-its-possible-to-wait-reponse-from-client)

Comment: @ilkerkaran I am using Mediator in my Website. I guess that makes it event-driven architecture as every different unique action has its own command handler

Comment: @Larry its a good article but unfortunately thats not what my goal is. As I am not waiting for a response from the client. My goal is somewhat create a reliable bridge  between client and service which are on different platforms. Like Web,Desktop,iOS.

Comment: So you have a client C, a website W, and a service S. C make http calls to W, you want W to query S then send the answer back to C ? Have I understood well ?