# Best way to do Request-Response to an Edge/near-device program

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, signalr

I have a cloud server which handles multiple tenants. We have an integration engine in that handles device commands. Sometimes, these commands requires sending signals to physical devices or reading from serial/USB ports.

These device commands are case-to-case basis and we have a wide range of edge programs with different tech stack in those integrations, any especially legacy tech. My question now is, what is the best way to send a command (request-response) from a cloud application to one of these integration programs. My idea has been something like this:

```
Cloud Server <-> Communication Service <-> Integration Program
```

My Cloud server is an ASP.NET Core project so my initial thought would be, to be more specific

```
ASP.NET Controller SignalR Hub <-> SignalR Windows Service to manage connections/calls <-> IPC <-> Integration Program
```

To phrase the question in another wording, what is the best way to build a request-response infrastructure to a edge program, where the cloud server can actually send commands to the edge program and vice versa. Assuming the edge program is behind NAT and whatnot, I think the communication service needs to establish the connection (socket, SignalR, MQTT?) and then the cloud server links (via GUIDs) and uses that same connection to send commands down to the integration program. In order to share the communication stack between different edge programs, the Communication Service in between would be used and IPC to transfer the data to the edge program.

Typical example scenario would be the following: there is a button in the cloud application UI, "Open Door" which is a method in the IEdgeProgramCapabilities, this sends an HTTP POST request to the cloud server's ASP.NET Controller, which finds right SignalR client and sends the "Open Door" request to the right communication service (which should be constantly connected otherwise it wont work), the communication service receive the "Open Door" command and passes it to an old .NET 4.5 program which writes a something with USB to a door controller, gets a response OK and sends it back all the way to the cloud server.

Typical hardware where the Communication Service and Edge Program would run is regular desktop PCs, embedded devices and low-end devices, so typically not server infrastructure.

I noted that in .NET 7, SignalR can do Request-Response ([Signalr - It's possible to wait reponse from client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48288284/signalr-its-possible-to-wait-reponse-from-client)). But would really like to know if there are any better methods of doing this. Especially with respect to the IEdgeProgramCapabilities.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at Azure IoT Hub sounds like it might be a good fit for you.

Comment: Azure IoT Hub seems like a good option. However, I wont have a lot of devices and I guess my UI even would like to do polling for values etc and I dont see a whats the main benefit of the IoT Hub rather than a SignalR connection in this case? Doesn't seem very cost effective when I will send a lot of data back and forth.

Comment: The advantage to Azure IoT Hub/IoT Edge is mainly scalability. SignalR, if I remember correctly, is limited to 1000 connections, or something of the sort -- but if number of devices isn't an issue, then this is a moot point. In any case, you could also take a look at using a messaging queue such as Azure ServiceBus. You won't be able to wait for a response, and communications would rather be asynchronous. I've personally had issues with SignalR dropped connections and failed re-connects, etc. which drove me to a queue based solution.

Comment: I don't see what benefit I get by using the Azure IoT Hub rather than some scalability that I most likely wont need. As far as I understand the IoT Hub does not help me with the encapsulation of the method interface anyway so I would need to pass method strings and parameters ad-hoc/untyped anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Azure cloud, application insights, allows you to create a middleware component that can trace, basically, whatever you want from your request/response objects.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core?tabs=netcorenew%2Cnetcore6

This works well with the ILogger interface, that you should be using in C# already.

In your middleware, you can make a telemtry handler, that will grab requests, based anything present in the http request, and log whatever you want, await the response, and then store that also, with whatever you want.

Key words are: ILogger, Telemetry and Middleware.

I am sure there are similar systems on other cloud providers, I am just not familiar with those.

If you want specific data from your device logging to be present, you can store it as part of the response handling into "CustomDimensions" a field on the telemetry part, for basically, whatever you want.

Or you can trace that directly into application insights logging.

If you use ILogger to trace your messages, you can also implement a new ILogger, if you don't want to use application insights.